# segmentation fault when try reading binary file using overloaded operator >>

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading, fstream, binary-data

I am trying read a binary file which was created with code like that:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <fstream>

struct Node {
  char data;
  int frequency;

  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Node& e) {
    input.read(&e.data, sizeof(e.data));
    input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(e.frequency), sizeof(e.frequency));
    return input;
  };

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Node& e) {
    output.write(&e.data, sizeof(e.data));
    output.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&e.frequency), sizeof(e.frequency));
    return output;
  };
};

int main() {
  std::list<struct Node> list;

  for(char i='a'; i<='z'; i++) {
    struct Node n;
    n.data = i;
    n.frequency = 1;
    list.push_back(n);
  }

  std::string encoded_file = "";

  for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    encoded_file = encoded_file + "101010";
  }

  std::fstream output;
  output.open("output.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);

  if (output.is_open()) {
    output << list.size();
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
      output << list.front();
      list.pop_front();
    }

    for(long unsigned int i=0; i<encoded_file.length(); i+=8) {
      std::string data = encoded_file.substr(i, 8);
      std::bitset<8> b(data);
      unsigned long x = b.to_ulong();
      unsigned char c = static_cast<unsigned char>( x );
      output << c;
    }
  }

  output.close();

  return 0;
}
```

This code seems to work fine, and the file `output.txt` is generated without problems.

But, when I try reading the file with this code:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
  char data;
  int frequency;

  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Node& e) {
    input.read(&e.data, sizeof(e.data));
    input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(e.frequency), sizeof(e.frequency));
    return input;
  };

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Node& e) {
    output.write(&e.data, sizeof(e.data));
    output.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&e.frequency), sizeof(e.frequency));
    return output;
  };
};

int main() {
  std::list<struct Node> list;
  std::string encoded_file = "";

  std::fstream input;
  input.open("output.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);

  if (input.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    int size = 0;
    input >> size;
    std::cout << "size: " << size << std::endl;

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
      Node node;
      input >> node;
      std::cout << node.data << " (" << node.frequency << ")" << std::endl;
      list.push_back(node);
    }
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;

    char c;
    while(input.get(c)) {
      std::bitset<8> b(c);
      encoded_file = encoded_file + b.to_string();
    }
    std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
  }

  input.close();

  return 0;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault. The error occurs when I try to execute `input >> node;`. I checked, and apparently when the program enters `Node::operator>>`, `e.data` is read, but frequency is not.

Can anyone give me any tips of how to fix this?

Comment: Missing an `&` here? `input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(e.frequency)`

Comment: Also, the code that's writing the file is completely broken. Looks like `list` gets populated with 26 values, but if you will use your debugger to step through the code, one line at a time, you will be surprised to discover that the first `for` loop will not iterate 26 times.

Comment: In the C++ standard, `operator<<` and `opeator>>` on steams are **formatted** operators; they operate on **text**. There's nothing to prevent you from writing your own operators that don't respect that convention, but sooner or later somebody's going to get very confused.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `std::fstream input; input.open("output.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);` to `std::fstream input("output.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);`. Also, for **input**, use an input stream: `std::ifstream input("output.txt", std::ios_base::binary);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `Node::operator>>`. When reading `e.frequency`, you are missing a `&`:

```
input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&e.frequency), sizeof(e.frequency));
                                   ^
```

That was a typo in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72428424/65863) where you got this code from. I have corrected that mistake.

---

With that said, I see other problems in your code.

You are creating the file in binary mode, but you are not streaming everything into it as binary values. Only your `Node` class is being streamed as binary, but your other values are being streamed as text instead. Don't mix formatting schemes.

`output << list.size()` and `output << c` are performing formatted I/O. Use `write()` instead of `operator<<` for binary I/O, eg:

```
size_t size = list.size();
output.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size));
...
unsigned char c = ...;
output.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&c), sizeof(c));
```

And then reverse that process when reading the file, eg:

```
input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size));
...
unsigned char c;
while(input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&c), sizeof(c))) {
     ...
}
```

Also, in your code that is creating the file, your 1st `for` loop is wrong.  You are modifying the `list` while looping through it, thus affecting its `size()`. So you end up skipping nodes in the list.  You should iterate using iterators instead of indexes, and without modifying the list at all, eg:

```
for(std::list<Node>::const_iterator iter = list.cbegin(); iter != list.cend(); ++iter) {
    output << *iter;
}
```

Or simpler:

```
for(const auto &item : list) {
    output << item;
}
```